# Performance issue in attaching template programmatically

Tags: .net, vsto

I am creating an add-in for Word 2010 which integrates with another third-party Word template and loads it programmatically. Shown below is the code which loads the 3rd party add-in:

```
Application.AddIns.Add("3rdPartyAddinName.dot");
```

I cannot put this `.dot` file in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Word\Startup` folder as we would do normally (due to a business requirement).

We are facing huge performance issue when we attach templates through code. A blank Word document takes around **35-40 seconds** to launch and become editable. However, when we put this template in the STARTUP folder, the launch time reduces drastically to around 2-3 seconds.

Any pointers about the correct way to load templates programmatically will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the startup cost remain constant without using the **third-party Word template**?

Comment: Yes. It does. Around 2-3 seconds.